# How Can I Specify All Members of a Set Are Unique in Alloy?

Tags: alloy

I have an alloy model.  In the spirit of a small reproduction example, I've extracted the following:

```
sig SearchTerm {}
sig Document{
    keyword: set SearchTerm
}

assert keywordsAreUniqueForDocument {
    all k, k' : Document.keyword | k != k'
}

check keywordsAreUniqueForDocument for 5
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that the set of keywords associated with a particular document should be unique.  But this is immediately showing me a trivial counterexample.

How can I specify that there should be no duplicated elements in a set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.keyword` is a set and, by the set definition, is only unique elements. You're getting a counterexample where `k = k'`. If you instead write  `all disj k, k' : Document.keyword | k != k'`, it will trivially pass.

If you instead intended that no two *documents* share keywords, that'd be `all disj d, d': Document | no d.keywork & d'.keyword`.

Comment: Thank you @Hovercouch.  I thought that sets are only supposed to allow unique elements but I wasn't sure that alloy sets would conform to that behavior.   Just want to make sure I'm following you--I don't need the assertion at all because by definition all keywords should be unique for each document.  Am I following you correctly?